# Bootstrap in not loading as expected in angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have installed bootstrap and jquery using npm install and it's shown in node_modules. Then I included them in angular.json file shown below:

```
"styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"

            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"

            ]
```

Below is my code for navbar in app.component.html file

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I am not getting the expected output

Comment: Have you tried importing jquery first in your index.html? jquery is needed to be imported first for bootstrap navbar menu to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you never should use JQuery with Angular because Angular uses something called virtual DOM which manipulating with DOM for you, if you use jquery you can run into some problems or bugs if you don't setup your component properly.

But if you realy wan't to add it don't install it via npm, just import it from CDN because there a is a very big chance user did go on some page that uses Jquery (from CDN) so he have cached the JQ in browster which results in quicker load of you page the same goes for bootstrap.

Just add this to the header in index.html file:

For Bootstrap:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

For JQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But again if you wan't to include it from your own machine just look to the console if there is some error. if there is none look to the generated html (in browster) the import should be included at the end of the HTML. If there is none try to restart dev server.

BTW including from file is great for dev, but you can use CDN for dev to since it will get cached.

Hope this helped.